# Show/movie from the late '80s where an extraterrestrial girl causes pool balls to float above a table

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens, tv

It may have been a made-for-TV movie, or perhaps a *Tales from the Crypt* / *Tales from the Darkside* episode. I don't remember much of the plot, although it was likely the typical alien-on-the-run-from-the-government-baddies. Maybe the girl wasn't even an alien, but that's what I seem to recall. I just remember that scene, where I think she was showing what she could do to someone else. No CGI involved in the effects.

The girl was probably in her late teens or early twenties.

Comment: The girl from tomorrow had a few scenes where Alana was training or demonstrating abilities by levitating balls over a table. From the future rather than an alien though.

Comment: The pilot episode actually has levitating purple balls, although they aren't pool balls. https://youtu.be/NRO8gvpPVoQ?t=55

Comment: Definitely not The Girl from Tomorrow. There was no CGI (and those purple balls are Video-Toaster-era effects), and I believe the girl in question was in her late teens or early twenties.

Comment: @Brad303 Was it a physical special effect? The age is good - anything else you can remember and edit in to the question may help to recall the answer.

Comment: Could it be "Starcrossed" with James Spader? There is a scene where the alien girl levitates snooker balls in a snooker hall.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Clara notes above, this is almost certainly [*Starcrossed*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0090066/), a made-for-TV movie of 1985.

As part of an entirely too-long scene in a pool hall, the billiard balls begin to float [right about here](https://youtu.be/7Jf7c2XJg-4?t=1775).

Comment: Ding! Ding! Ding! We have a correct answer! Thanks, Clara (and Maury)! Completely forgot James Spader was in it, but watching the clip everything "clicked".